# Window.Close not working

Tags: jquery

I have a click event of a button in jquery inside which I am trying to close the window like below:

```
$('#myControl').click(function(){

   window.close();

})
```

but the window is not getting closed instead it's giving me an error that window can not be closed as it is not opened from here.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve it??

Comment: The error message says it all: that's how things are. It's a security feature.

Comment: Where did you open the window?

Comment: Why are you closing a window in the first place? Let the user decide what windows they want open..

Comment: I opened this from another window through a click of an anchor tag

Comment: Can you show that anchor tag? And the code if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are opening the page from a control which is in another page . You can solve it with below code:

```
//Closing the current window
    window.open('', '_self', '', '');
    window.close();
```